# Find file name recursively that contains matched pattern or by 99b and then delete

Tags: linux, bash, shell, ssh, terminal

A few sites on one of my servers was hacked. I have cleaned them, but I noticed they added inside each directory a .htaccess file which I need to go through and remove.

I have this so far. This lists all found matched files with pattern match

```
find . -name ".htaccess" | xargs grep -i '<FilesMatch ".(py|exe|phtml|php|PhP|php5|suspected)$">'
```

which returns a list of found files for reference the contents of the .htaccess files is:

```
<FilesMatch ".(py|exe|phtml|php|PhP|php5|suspected)$">
  Order Allow,Deny
  Deny from all
</FilesMatch>
```

The file sizes are always 99 from what I can see when doing a ls -al in terminal

I'm not sure of the safest way, maybe adding -size as well but I've been trying with no success, so though it was best to double-check.

What I am mainly struggling with is executing removal of the files found.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this might be what you're looking for?

```
#!/bin/bash
# Loop over each file spit out by the find command
while IFS= read -r -d '' ht_file; do
    # If the file contents match the pattern, delete it
    if grep -q -i '<FilesMatch ".(py|exe|phtml|php|PhP|php5|suspected)$">' "$ht_file"; then
        rm -f "$ht_file"
    fi
done < <(find . -name ".htaccess" -print0)
```

Comment: not sure if it worked, should of checked files before running but did not output any result or is it not meant to?

Comment: `rm -f` doesn't print any output so you wouldn't have seen anything. You could try adding an `echo "Deleting $ht_file"` before the `rm -f` to see what's being deleted. If it was successful before though, there wouldn't be any matches!

Comment: You shouldn't post code that may cause irreversible data loss.